# Redmine installation issue on bluehost shared hosting

Tags: ruby, rubygems, redmine

I followed every step described in [Redmine installation](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall) page and in [this article](http://www.activesplit.com/how-to-install-redmine-on-bluehost/comment-page-1).

I put the following path in `environment.rb`:

```
ENV['GEM_PATH'] = '/home/myusername/ruby/gems/gems:/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8'
```

I tried the following path too:

```
ENV['GEM_PATH'] = '/home/myusername/ruby/gems:/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8'
```

Still there is an error when I'm trying to execute the command

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake config/initializers/session_store.rb
```

Error message is the following:

```
Missing the i18n 0.4.2 gem. Please `gem install -v=0.4.2 i18n`
```

Although gem is there with the specific verison.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

try with this

```
export GEM_HOME=$HOME/ruby/gems/
```

Bye.

Comment: I was able to resolve it by doing almost this, but I had to manually enter the full path listed under "Location of your Ruby Gems" on Bluehost's gem management webpage:

export GEM_HOME=/home1/accountname/ruby/gems

Answer (score 0):

did you set those environment variables and install the gems there, I assume?